# Change font size for Facebook Comments Social Plugin – Number of Comments on page

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-comments

So I am attempting to increase the font size when displaying the number of comments for a given page.  I am using the iFrame code provided by Facebook.  Initially I added CSS attributes directly into the iFrame, but that was unsuccessful.  Since that point I’ve been trying to use Javascript to alter the style of the iFrame. Any ideas?

```
<iframe id="FBFrame" src="<?php echo $FBURL; ?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> 

<script>
   document.getElementById('FBFrame').style.fontSize = "20px";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with css since javascript is blocked

something like

```
#facebook body{
//facebook is the document id facebook gives to the iframe content
font-size:20px
}
```

should work

Comment: I added the above CSS to one of my style sheets, but it failed to override the iFrame attributes from Facebook.

Comment: try adding `!important;`